# Dependency Injection/config object

Tags: oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have an object that is responsible for exporting a file to csv.

It works well but i am looking at ways to refactor it.

This question pertains to the constructor which takes a number of arguments, relating to how the csv is to be exported:

For example, file name, delimiter, etc. etc.

Also, lately I have been reading about dependency injection but cant decide if this is a case where I should:

A. Leave the constructor as is.
B. Create a new class that gets passed to the constructor that simple holds config values for the file name etc
C. Something else altogether?

Here is the existing constructor (in PHP)

```
    public function __construct($file,$overwriteExistingFile, $enclosure, $delim, $headerRow)
    {
        //set all properties here
    }
```

Comment: probably should post some code for context. Do you *need* to refactor it, or is this just an intellectual exercise? If it works fine as is, chances are you don't need to re(over)engineer unless it's somehow tightly coupled to other code.

Comment: Post the existing constructor and we'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: Its an intellectual exercise, trying to learn the best way to do this type of thing

Comment: @BryanWatts thanks i have updated for you.  thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of those values represents data that is an input to some process. `$enclosure`, `$delimiter`, and `$headerRow` pertain to generating the CSV content, while `$file` and `$overwriteExistingFile` pertain to persisting the content to disk.

A hallmark of a DI-style refactoring is to identify the various responsibilities (generate, persist) and encapsulate *each* of them in its own type. This shifts the refactoring from "how do I best get the values *to* this class?" to "how do I remove knowledge of these values *from* this class?"

To answer that, we would define two new concepts, each of which takes one of the responsibilities, and pass those into the existing constructor:

```
public function __construct($csvGenerator, $csvFileWriter)
{
    ...save dependencies...
}

...at some point, generate the CSV content and pass it to the file writer...
```

In this way, the original class becomes the orchestrator of the interaction between the generation and file writing, without having intimate knowledge of either activity. We have elevated the class to a higher level of abstraction, simplifying it as well as isolating its responsibilities into its collaborators.

Now, you would define two *new* classes, constructing them with the relevant parameters:

**Generator**

```
public function __construct($enclosure, $delimiter, $headerRow)
```

**File Writer**

```
public function __construct($file, $overwriteExistingFile)
```

With these elements in place, you can compose them together by creating the generator, then the file writer, then passing both to the orchestrator.

Comment: that sounds really interesting and makes sense.  Is it accepted with this style of coding that there is more upfront work in getting things to work.  For example, instead of $csvClass = new CsvClass('myacefile.csv' etc etc); we now have two initialise two other objects and then initialise the csvclass.  So is the all still ok to do this?

Comment: @user1189880: Yes, that is an accepted style of coding. It splits your application into two phases: the composition phase, followed by the execution phase. You would generally have a DI container to help you with the composition, a concept you have undoubtedly encountered if you have been reading about DI.

Comment: @user1189880: In addition, this style results in smaller chunks of logic which can be combined in interesting ways. For example, now that CSV generation is decoupled from CSV file writing, you could generate CSV content and do things like show it in a UI or send it to a web service. Or, you could write a file with pre-generated CSV content.

Comment: Perfect thanks for your answer, makes perfect sense to me.  I have one last question in relation to you comment: if i am creating the classes as described in your answer in addition to some other services required that work with the csv writer then would this be a good situation for a container?  So i would initliase a single container or seperate containers for each part of logic?

Comment: Generally you would have a single container for the whole application, then ask for a single root object (see http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx for more information). However, it would probably be fine in your case to have multiple containers, if you have an existing application to which you are adding DI. Just don't mix objects from them - only have one container in effect for a given piece of work.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `CSVFormatter` that you can setup the deliminator on and unit test the formatting independently with.

Inject the formatter into a `CSVWriter` which writes the formatted output to a file.

The reason you would do this is to unit test the formatting logic or if you need to do multiple kinds of formatting or write to different kinds of output streams.  If the code is very small and simple then you don't need to break it into multiple classes.

Comment: That was my thinking with point B in my question.  The problem i considered with this was that, i still need create that object and pass the required values for delimter etc to its constructor.  If you see what i mean?

Comment: If your main concern is the number of arguments in the constructor, you can make them fields that can be set and use a default value.  For instance ',' can be the default deliminator but you can have a `setDeliminator` method.  You can also [introduce a parameter object](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html), but that probably doesn't make sense here.

Comment: its not the number of arguments but, the pros and cons of using the object (which i would need a similar constructor for) to pass in as opposed to using the constructor